# How to change the color of an in three.js loaded object with JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I loaded an object in Three.js with the AssimpJSONLoader.
The object cube_cone is a simple 3D model which contains a cube which has a cone on top of it.

```
var loader1 = new THREE.AssimpJSONLoader(); 
loader1.load( 'models/assimp/cube_cone.json', function ( object ) {
        object.scale.multiplyScalar( 1 );
        object.material.color.setHex(0x666666);
        scene.add( object );

}, onProgress, onError );
```

First of all I want to change the color of the object. How do I do it? I tried it with: "object.material.color.setHex(...);".

Second of all I only want to manipulate the color of a child object, e.g. just the cone. The test_cone.json object has "children" with "name": "3DSMesh_0" and "name": "3DSMesh_1". How can I access them to manipulate just a part of the object and not the whole?

I would be very thankful if you can help me because I am a beginner in Javascript.

Comment: try `var part1 = object.getObjectByName('3DSmesh_1');`, then `part1.material.color.setHex(...);`

Comment: Thank you, with getObjectByName() I achieved to manipulate the children nodes. But with part1.material.color.setHex(0x666666); for example the color of the object doesn't change.

Comment: What type of material there? like `console.log(part1.material);`.

Comment: thanks I figured it out. Do you know how to access the object outside the loader? For example I want to have access to the object to make functions with it. I tried with "loader1.load( '...', function ( object ) { return object;}" and tried to "scene.add( object );" outside the loader but it didn't work.

Comment: declare a global variable, for example `var myObj;`, and then inside of `onLoad()` callback set is as `myObj = object`

Comment: Could you give me an example code pls? I don't know what you mean with creating a callback set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to make an example as an answer for your last comment.

```
var myObj = new THREE.Group(); //global variable
...
var loader1 = new THREE.AssimpJSONLoader(); 
loader1.load( 'models/assimp/cube_cone.json', function ( object ) {//onLoad callback
    myObj = object; //assign object to the global variable inside the callback
}, onProgress, onError );
...
function animate(){
    ...
    myObj.rotation.y += 0.1;// using the global variable in your animation function
    ...
}
```

also you can assign a child of an `object`, for example

```
myObj = object.getObjectByName("3DSMesh_1", true);
```

Comment: If I want to make the child object `cube= object.getObjectByName("3DSMesh_1", true);` shine like a lamp do you know how I can do this? I already have access to the child and create a DirectionalLight. But how can I set the light to the cube so that the whole cube shines? Do I have to test the coordinates of the cube or can I add the light to the cube? And second do you think a DirectionalLight or a PointLight is better? (That is just an example for my project where I want the frontlights/backlights of a car to shine)

Comment: I think it's better to put as another question on SO

Comment: Ok, thanks! I did it yesterday: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793978/how-to-make-a-part-of-a-json-object-glow)